# HttpSession.invalidate() and TCPDUMP

Tags: java, http, tomcat, session-cookies, tcpdump

I use TCPDUMP to track some applications' HTTP traffic, running under certain processes (IP@ + Port).

When I invoke a page, TCPDUMP does indeed show the whole traffic behavior.

Even when I sign in through a Login/Password form, the generated traffic includes Set-Cookie header (JSessionID cookie).

However, I wonder why there is no meaningful traffic when I log out; namely, when the server side executes HTTPSession's invalidate() method, no meaningful HTTP information is yielded by Tomcat/Servlet Container.

How to catch the session termination in HTTP with Tomcat using TCPDUMP?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to see. The session is invalidated at the server, but that doesn't generate any traffic. The *next* HTTP request will see the 302 response code or whatevwr it is, if there is a next request.